# Notice: Undefined index: extension in /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php on line 806

Tags: error, magento2.4, file-upload

I'm adding Vimeo movies to my products. The first one to add works flawless. If I open another product and try to add another movie I get this error: Notice: Undefined index: extension in /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php on line 806

Anybody an idea why this is happening and how to fix it? My Magento version is 2.4.2-p2

Comment: Apply this patch and checking - https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405321730445-MDVA-38308-Error-after-adding-Vimeo-videos-to-disabled-products

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of this patch, but it did not solve my problem. Found out that this error only comes up when I try to add the same video to another product in one session.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue with the next way:

Assuming that you have some module, for example, Vendor_ProductVideo.

Taking into account that function getNewFileName() in Uploader class is static, I've added preference in di.xml to the class where it calls.

Vendor\ProductVideo\etc\di.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ProductVideo\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery\RetrieveImage"
            type="Vendor\ProductVideo\Rewrite\Magento\ProductVideo\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery\RetrieveImage"/>
</config>
```

Vendor\ProductVideo\Rewrite\Magento\ProductVideo\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery\RetrieveImage content:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductVideo\Rewrite\Magento\ProductVideo\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery;

use Vendor\ProductVideo\Model\File\Uploader;

/**
 * Class RetrieveImage
 */
class RetrieveImage extends \Magento\ProductVideo\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery\RetrieveImage
{
    /**
     * @param string $localFilePath
     * @return string
     */
    protected function appendNewFileName($localFilePath)
    {
        $destinationFile = $this->appendAbsoluteFileSystemPath($localFilePath);
        $fileName = Uploader::getNewFileName($destinationFile);
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($localFilePath);
        return $fileInfo['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
    }
}
```

And I've used Uploader class, inherited from magento framework's one, but changed getNewFileName() function a little bit. Added check for the existence of a file extension, and if no file extension exists, it just modifies the base filename.

Here is the content of \Vendor\ProductVideo\Model\File\Uploader class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductVideo\Model\File;

class Uploader extends \Magento\Framework\File\Uploader
{
    /**
     * Get new file name if the same is already exists
     *
     * @param string $destinationFile
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getNewFileName($destinationFile): string
    {
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($destinationFile);

        if (file_exists($destinationFile)) {
            $index = 1;
            $extension = isset($fileInfo['extension']) && array_key_exists('extension', $fileInfo)
            && trim($fileInfo['extension']) !== '' ? '.' . $fileInfo['extension'] : '';
            $baseName = $fileInfo['filename'] . $extension;

        while (file_exists($fileInfo['dirname'] . '/' . $baseName)) {
            $baseName = $fileInfo['filename'] . '_' . $index . $extension;
            $index++;
        }
        $destFileName = $baseName;
        } else {
            return $fileInfo['basename'];
        }

        return $destFileName;
    }
}
```

This helped in my case.